# swift - CCBReader symbol not found

Tags: ios, swift, cocos2d-iphone, spritebuilder

Currently I am trying to accomplish with Cocos2d-swift+SpriteBuilder and their tutorial provided [there](http://www.spritebuilder.com/blog/furry-feathers)

I am trying to do this not in Objective-C but in Swift. So during the tutorial I have faced with the issue when Xcode can't find `CCBReader`.

As I can see from the project structure, it is in place. The place where I stuck is:

`var ball: CCNode = CCBReader.load("Bird")`

In the tutorial this line looks like:

`CCNode *ball = [CCBReader load:@"Bird"];`

The main problem is that I can't get access to the CCBReader while it presents in the libs.

Could someone help me with this please?

Answer (score 1):

This issue was fixed by Cocos2d-Swift 3.4beta + SpriteBuilder 1.4.
http://forum.spritebuilder.com/t/spritebuilder-1-4-beta-release/2573